# PHP passing incrementation type throw a variable

Tags: php

How can I pass the type of incrementation throw a variable like the example bellow:

```
function next_prev_elem($step_id, $array, $incre){
    foreach ($array as $i) {
        $incre.$step_id;
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if($step_id === $item['id']){
                return $step_id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$prev_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, '--');
$next_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, '++');
```

Comment: you can't pass operators, but you can test for strings. `if ($incre == '++') { $var++; } else {$var--;}` That or pass in the actual increment value. `next_prev_elem(...., -1)` and `next_prev_element(..., 1)` and just add it in. passing in positive/negative values will naturally take care of the "direction".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marc B, I ended up with this solution:

```
function next_prev_elem($step_id, $array, $step){
    foreach ($array as $i) {
        $step_id = $step_id + $step;
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if($step_id === $item['id']){
                return $step_id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$prev_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, -1);
$next_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function next_prev_elem($step_id, $array, $incre){
    foreach ($array as $i) {

        switch( $incre ) {
          case '++':
            $step_id++;
            break;
          case '--':
            $step_id--;
            break;
        }

        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if($step_id === $item['id']){
                return $step_id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$prev_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, '--');
$next_id = next_prev_elem($id, $page_news, '++');
```